# Is there a way to figure out how a previously installed package was installed when upgrading?

Tags: managed-package, package-install, upgrade, installedpackage

I want to upgrade a package, however I want to be careful when installing. Is there a way to see historically which option was chosen when installing a package?

- Install for Admins Only
- Install for All Users
- Install for Specific Profiles...

[image]

> **Note**: I see that if I choose 'Install for Specific Profiles...' option
>   that all Profiles have 'No Access'. I guess in this instance then my
>   answer is easy - it's was installed with 'Install for Admins Only'.
>   However is that the only way to find out?

Comment: I see that if I choose 'Install for Specific Profiles...' option that all Profiles have 'No Access'. I guess in this instance then my answer is easy - it's was installed with 'Install for Admins Only'. However is that the only way to find out?